# ConstraintLayout space between Views

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

At the moment I'm playing a bit with the new `ConstraintLayout` and try to create the following layout:

[image]

> (1) Headline: Type 24sp, Leading 32sp
>   (2) Subhead 1: Type 15sp, Leading 24sp
>   (3) 32sp line height
>   (4) 56dp padding between the top of button and the center of copy
>   (5) 24dp vertical padding

My problem now is that I do not know how I should handle the sizes which refer to the center of the second `TextView`. We do not have a constraint for the center (or baseline) to bottom or something like this. Also I'm not able to set a space between two views which are connected between the baseline points. So how should I create this layout with the ConstraintLayout?

Can someone please give me a sample layout from the picture above?

Comment: use chain attribut  ` app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread" ` to equaly distribute the width between views, 
` app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside" ` to distribute the views aside and set space between views, and
 ` app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed" `  to pack the views togather and extra space is distribute around the views, based on other contraints.,,,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We only allow baseline to baseline, without margin for now. We might revisit this in the future, but as of ConstraintLayout alpha 7 you cannot do this. The only option is to align with top / bottom.

[image]

Comment: Hi Nicolas, instead of set `marginTop=48dp` on textView1, how to center everything?

Comment: You can use chains (packed chain) for this -- check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains

Comment: An accepted answer that uses an image of the code it suggests instead of the actual code? Sorry, but that is an absolute no go.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a view with a layout height as a divider, then reference the bottom of the divider